# change data capture from a MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, haproxy, cdc

I need to capture changes, using a CDC binlog client, from a MariaDB Galera cluster (v10.3.10) with a load balancer in front of it.

[image: MariaDB Galera HA]

MariaDB Galera Cluster with a load balancer provides fault tolerance. If a node dies, the load balancer health check detects that and routes traffic to the other nodes. That's good. We want high availability.

The CDC client works perfectly when connected directly to any of the cluster nodes. However, when the CDC client connects to the MariaDB Galera cluster via the HAProxy load balancer, it fails:

> Could not find first log file name in binary log index file

Presumably, the client connects to the one of the nodes, gets a filename, positions, etc... and a subsequent request is routed to a different node which has different binlog properties.

Is there a way to CDC from a highly available MariaDB Galera cluster that doesn't depend on a single node? We'd like to avoid single points of failure.

Comment: (Deleted my previous Comment; it was addressed by edits to Question.)